# What caused the day/night cycles on Star Base Yorktown

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond, star-trek-reboot

In Star Trek: Beyond, star base Yorktown is in space, not in orbit. What creates the day and night cycles, as we see both of these during the film

Comment: They turn the lights down?

Comment: @JoeL. Maybe, but the light coming from the outer shield, and it looks way too natural to her artificial

Comment: A damn good question. I've rewatched to look at light sources. The base appears to be in orbit of a small white star which is only ever glimped in reflections and at the very top of the screen (mostly shaded by lens-flare). There's no good indication how they turn the lights down. Presumably it's polarised glass?

Comment: @Valorum fair point. But the questions that now is raised is  having light is a lot more accessible (in terms of activity and safety) why not put electrochroamatic  glass in rooms and allow people to have a preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yorktown isn't just hanging in deep space. It's in orbit of a small, white star. You can glimpse it in a number of scenes as a reflection.

[image]

and in this 'blink and you'll miss it' scene as the bottom edge of the star clips the frame.

[image]

As to how they manage the day/night cycle, that isn't immediately apparent. I think we can assume that the "glass" is polarised in some fashion and that it can simply be darkened when they want the station to experience a night period.